# Window deactivation message?

Tags: windows, winapi

What is the opposite of **WM_ACTIVATE** (Window deactivation message)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same message, but with a different argument - wparam = WA_INACTIVE.

Full details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The message *is* WM_ACTIVATE. This message is sent both when the window is activated, and when it is deactivated. You can tell if it is deactivated by looking at the wParam parameter - either it is WA_ACTIVE or WA_CLICKACTIVE (activated), or it is WA_INACTIVE (inactivated).